# How to image resize before upload Dropzone in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i used [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) but this package doesn't support rezise. 
How to rezise image and than upload it?

```
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles } = useDropzone({
    multiple: props.multiple,
    accept: props.acceptedFileTypes,
    maxFilesize: 100,
    onDrop: acceptedFiles => {
    if (acceptedFiles.length > 0) {
    // i uploaded images.
    upload(acceptedFiles)
     }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/krmgk883/

Comment: i will try it thank you.

Comment: fyi, when you resize images with the canvas element you loose a bit of compression. eg i took my gravatar image that where around 100k and ended up with 300k without any modification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated my answer to refer to imtool instead (which is nailit with a different API and more features). Original answer is below.

To solve this problem you can use [imtool](https://npmjs.com/package/imtool) which is a spiritual successor to nailit.

Updated example:

```js
//...other imports
import { fromImage } from 'imtool';

const [ fileURL, setFileURL ] = useState(null);

const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    setFileURL(reader.result);
}, false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (acceptedFiles[0]) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(acceptedFiles[0]);
    }
}, [ acceptedFiles ]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (fileURL) {
        // Parameters: 250 is the maximum size and false is the cover argument.
        fromImage(fileURL)
        .then(tool => tool.thumbnail(250, false).toBlob())
        .then(blob => {
            // You can add the resulting blob to a FormData element and then send that.
            const formData = new FormData();
            form.append('image', blob, 'image.jpg');
            fetch('https://example.com/image', { method: 'POST', body: formData });
        }
        .catch(e => /* Do something with the error! */);
    }
}, [ fileURL ]);
```

For documentation, please refer to the README in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/mat-sz/imtool).

---

Some time ago I've made a library to perform this exact task.

It's available on npm - [nailit](https://npmjs.com/package/nailit) (I've just pushed an update, make sure you get the 2.0.1 version). And here is an example project with nailit and react-dropzone: https://github.com/mat-sz/nailit-demo

It works by creating a canvas and resizing image in the web browser.

Example:

```js
const [ fileURL, setFileURL ] = useState(null);

const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    setFileURL(reader.result);
}, false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (acceptedFiles[0]) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(acceptedFiles[0]);
    }
}, [ acceptedFiles ]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (fileURL) {
        // Parameters: file data URI, options and should output be a blob (if you want to POST it then yes)
        nailIt(fileURL, {
            maxSize: 250,
            cover: false,
            outputType: 'image/jpeg',
            outputQuality: 0.7
        }, true).then((blob) => {
            // You can add the resulting blob to a FormData element and then send that.
            const formData = new FormData();
            form.append("image", blob, "image.jpg");
            fetch('https://example.com/image', { method: 'POST', body: formData });
        });
    }
}, [ fileURL ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for example. When i try it, i will return.

Comment: I've updated the library again to move the configuration to an object instead. Nothing has changed inside of the logic, just letting you know that I've changed the API.

Comment: I think nailit is need a quality option :)

Comment: There is an `outputQuality` option, if you need even better quality then you can set `outputType` to `image/png`.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention it, it's in all versions, but only now I've added some documentation (which is for 2.0.1).

Comment: I can't get correctly blob(https://pasteboard.co/ISJcy2X.png). Can you see this link?

Comment: Can any of you help with this I'm really stuck https://shorturl.at/lAMY3 @MatSz